# Android ViewModels: Should dataclasses expose livedata properties?

Tags: android, retrofit, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

Given this scenario:

Model

```
data class User(var id: int, var name: String)
```

View Model

```
val Users: LiveData<List<User>>
val SelectedUser: LiveData<User>

fun changeSelectedUserName(){SelectedUser.Name = "foo"}
```

UI

```
<android:TextView Text="@{viewmodel.SelectedUser.name}"/>
<android:Button Text="Change!" onClik="@{() -> viewmodel.changeSelectedUserName()}"/>
```

When user clicks 'Change!' button the textview won't change because the 'name' field is not LiveData.

Questions

- Should data class re-expose its fields as LiveData too?
- If so, what will happen to regular fields? Are they replaced or keeped with another naming convention?
- What is the correct naming convention if I'm using retrofit? So I can keep both the interface methods and LiveData working with the less amount of code?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are modifying the `User` object properties directly, rather than update the LiveData.

For this to work, you have to do one of the following:

- Make `User` extend `BaseObservable`, and invoke `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name)` when the `name` property changes, and remove the `LiveData<User>`.
- Make `User` extend `BaseObservable`, and put `@Bindable` annotation on the property getters, and remove `LiveData<User>`.
- Make `User` properties `val`, and to make a modification, create a new `User` instance with the changed properties, and set it as value of the `MutableLiveData<User>`.
- Ditch `SelectedUser` entirely, and replace it with two `ObservableField`s, one for `selectedId: ObservableInt`, and one for `selectedName: ObservableField<String>`. Now you can modify the values in place and also create bindings against it from databinding.
- Remove databinding and use viewbinding instead, now you don't have to worry about notifying the databinding framework of property changes.

> Should data class re-expose its fields as LiveData too?

No